# sending and recieving text to/from child process

Tags: c, pipe

I am trying to send some text from a parent process to a child process, which will process the text, and then send it back to the parent. Below is the code I have so far, but the read() call on line 30 hangs and I'm not sure how to debug it.

The `fd2` pipe is for the parent process to write a code string to, and the clang-format (child) process to read from.
The `fd` pipe is for the clang-format (child) process to write to and the parent process to read from.

In the child process branch I use dup2() to replace stdin and stdout with fd2 and fd1, which should then be inheritted as stdin and stdout by the clang-format process created by execlp.
In the parent process branch I write the code string for clang-format to process to `fd2[1]`, and read the output from `fd[0]`.

However, the read() call hangs. What am I doing wrong?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
  int fd[2];
  int fd2[2];
  pid_t childPid;
  pipe(fd);
  pipe(fd2);
  if ((childPid = fork()) == -1) {
    perror("fork");
    exit(1);
  }
  if (childPid == 0) {
    dup2(fd[1], 1);
    close(fd[0]);
    dup2(fd2[0], 0);
    close(fd2[1]);
    execlp("clang-format", "clang-format", (char *)NULL);
  } else {
    close(fd[1]);
    close(fd2[0]);
    char code[] = "void\n cool\n(int num){return num +1;}\n";
    size_t codeLen = strlen(code);
    write(fd2[1], code, codeLen);
    char buf[401];
    ssize_t msgLen = read(fd[0], buf, 400);
    buf[msgLen] = '\0';
    printf("message from child: %s :end of message.\n", buf);
  }
}
```

Comment: `clang-format` is likely waiting for an `EOF` on its read. Try closing `fd2[1]` in the parent process after the `write`.

Answer (score 0):

As per kaylum's comment, I needed to `close(fd2[1])` after writing to it. So full code is:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
  int fd[2];
  int fd2[2];
  pid_t childPid;
  pipe(fd);
  pipe(fd2);
  if ((childPid = fork()) == -1) {
    perror("fork");
    exit(1);
  }
  if (childPid == 0) {
    dup2(fd[1], 1);
    close(fd[0]);
    dup2(fd2[0], 0);
    close(fd2[1]);
    execlp("clang-format", "clang-format", (char *)NULL);
  } else {
    close(fd[1]);
    close(fd2[0]);
    char code[] = "void\n cool\n(int num){return num +1;}\n";
    size_t codeLen = strlen(code);
    write(fd2[1], code, codeLen);
    close(fd2[1]);
    char buf[401];
    ssize_t msgLen = read(fd[0], buf, 400);
    buf[msgLen] = '\0';
    printf("message from child: %s :end of message.\n", buf);
  }
}
```